# Running systemd unit directly after local-fs.target and before basic.target

Tags: systemd

I am creating an embedded system. The embedded system mounts a partition. Directly after mounting the partition, I need to prep an encrypted folder (encfs). I need this to run before any other `multi-user.target` or `graphical.target`

Here is my unit file, which works by it's self.

```
[Unit]
Description=Mx Encrypted Folder

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/bin/mxmountencrypted
RemainAfterExit=true
ExecStop=/usr/bin/mxunmountencrypted
```

This unit file has no dependencies defined, currently.

Again, I need:

1. To run this directly after mounting file systems (`local-fs.target`)
2. Before any `multi-user.target` or `graphical.target`, where must of the services that depend on it will be ran.
3. It must stop fully before stopping `local-fs.target`, since there will be a nested mount that needs to be unmounted before systemd can unmount the partition.

I looked into using the `systemd.mount` item, but it doesn't support `encfs`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on what you have listed in the requirements:

```
[Unit]
Description=Mx Encrypted Folder
Requires=local-fs.target
After=local-fs.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/bin/mxmountencrypted
RemainAfterExit=true
ExecStop=/usr/bin/mxunmountencrypted

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

More on systemd Unit files here: https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html

and systemd Service files: https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html